# How do I convert a POST form button into a link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on navigation for one project. The project is based on `Foundation Zurb 5+`, and for navigation I'm using `Top Bar`.

On the right ul list, have Steam Authorisation button, if user is not logged in. If he is logged in then I'm displaying his avatar and making a dropdown menu with some fields.

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
            <li class="steam-button has-dropdown">
                <?php
                    if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
                        steamlogin(); //login button
                    }  else {
                        include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');
                    ?>
                        <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $steamprofile['avatarmedium'] ?>" width=40px height=40px /></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Bla bla bla bla</a></li>
                            <li id="steam-logout-button"><?php logoutbutton() ?></li>
                        </ul>

                    <?php
                    }     
                ?>  

            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
            <!-- .... -->
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

The thing is that for `logoutbutton()` function I have:

```
function logoutbutton() {
    echo "<form action=\"steamauth/logout.php\" method=\"post\"><input class=\"\" value=\"Logout\" type=\"submit\" /></form>"; //logout button
}
```

And the question is how I can transform `logoutbutton()`'s `<form><input/></form>` to a `<li><a>Logout</a><li>`, because this input breaks my top bar.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If the button works properly and you just need to change it into a link, you should change this question's title. "Button not working properly" is not only really vague, but it doesn't appear to be true from your description.

Comment: @PhantomWatson Hi thanks for suggestion! How you could suggest to change the title?

Comment: "How do I convert a POST form button into a link?" should do it.

Comment: Can anyone comment why I've got a down vote on my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of [user3666802's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29170781/52530),

Since the original form is POST, and that might be important to logout.php, I suggest using `$.post()` instead of `$.get()`.

Put this anywhere in `<body>`:

```
<script>
    $('#logout').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("steamauth/logout.php");
    });
</script>
```

Replace `<?php logoutbutton() ?>` with

```
<a href="#" id="logout">
    Logout
</a>
```

And see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use Ajax to make a call to your logout script.

```
function logout(){
 $.get("steamauth/logout.php");
return false;
}

$('#logout').click(function(){
   logout();
})

<li><a id="logout">Logout</a><li>
```

Comment: Where the function logout() goes?